# Azure Data Factory - HDFS Copy Activity

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-data-factory

I'm migrating some data from my Hadoop On-Premise cluster to Azure ADLS.

I'm using Azure Data Factory (Copy Activity from HDFS) with an SHIR VM (Containing only one node for now). The connection is done via webhdfs.

I feel like the capacity of the node is not totally used, and that it's better to copy multiple small files/datasets rather than copying one big one (unlike Spark).

I'm doing a Binary copy and my Copy Activity looks like this :

[image]

I ran 7 copies for 7 datasets in Hadoop. When I have a look at one of the copy jobs, the parallel copies are just 2, and I have a slow throughput :
[image]

Finally when I have a look at the node monitoring, it looks like there are only 7 jobs (for 7 copies then) and that the rest is not used :
[image]

Any idea how I can optimize the copy, and use the full capacity of the my SHIR node ?
That would be the first step, next step is indeed adding more nodes.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to do similar copy using SHIR from HDFS to Azure. Data is copied for files which are not encrypted with keys at HDFS. However for encrypted files, I am unable to copy. As I see you mentioning SHIR, can you pplease help how are you doing binary copy for encrypted files from HDFS to Azure. Appreciate your help